# AngularJS data specific to a route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

What is the best way to pass specific data to a view controller?

How I imagined it to work you would add an extra property to the object. e.g `'data'`
See example below.

**Config:**

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('app', {
                    url: '/app',
                    abstract: true,
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
                    controller: 'AppCtrl'
                })

                .state('app.home', {
                    url: '/home',
                    views: {
                        'menuContent': {
                            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                            controller: 'pageController',
                            data: {foo: 'bar'}
                        }
                    }
                })

                .state('app.our-story', {
                    url: '/our-story',
                    views: {
                        'menuContent': {
                            templateUrl: 'templates/our-story.html',
                            controller: 'pageController',
                            data: {foo: 'bar2'}
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
    .controller('pageController', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $stateParams) {
        //Data passed from route config
        console.log(data);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using resolve to populate data into a service which can then be injected and consumed by your controller as follows:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/app',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
                controller: 'AppCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    somePromise: function(injectedService){
                        return injectedService.getSomeData();
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('app.home', {
                url: '/home',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                        data: {foo: 'bar'}
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('app.our-story', {
                url: '/our-story',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/our-story.html',
                        data: {foo: 'bar2'}
                    }
                }
            });
```

Back in the service, one would set the result of get some data to some private variable and create a function to return said variable as follows:

```
myApp.service('injectedService', ['injectedRepository', function(injectedRepository){
    var data;

    return {
        getSomeData: function(){
            injectedRepository.then(function(response){
                data = response.data;
            });
        },
        getData: function(){
            return data;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Finally, one would inject the service into the controller and use the service to retrieve the value of the data one needs.

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'injectedService', function($scope, injectedService){
    $scope.data = injectedService.getData();
});
```

Does that help?